# Switching to simulator during debugging

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

When you click on step into/over, xcode switches to show the simulation, although no changes have yet occurred. Slows down the debugging speed considerably. How can I disable the switch to simulator? I couldn't find it in the settings.

Comment: Could you give me more information, I don't understand exactly what happen on your Xcode? Xcode switches to show the simulation? if you can give an example or share image. thanks

Comment: You cannot easily prevent this at the moment, it's a very longstanding issue.

Comment: @RezaKhonsari, When you enable full screen mode for Xcode, we have two main screens between which you can switch with Ctrl+left/right: one screen for the simulation, the other for Xcode. When you press step into/over when debugging, the xcode screen switches to displaying the simulator screen, even though no changes have been made to the code (we went down to the next line when debugging). So if we have 100 lines of code, then every time we click on step into/over during debug, we will need to switch between screens 100 times.

Comment: Xcode sets a timer when you step, and only foregrounds the debugee if the step takes longer than the timer.  When I try what you describe I only see the debugee foregrounded if I step over a fairly long routine.  There isn't a way to tune this heuristic, but If it's not working in your configuration, you might file a bug with https://feedbackassistant.apple.com describing your setup and what you see.  Maybe these heuristics are missing some case or need some tuning.